# Tips for publishing draft manuscripts on arxiv

Tags: publications, career-path, paper-submission, arxiv

Some of you would probably know  the website http://arxiv.org/.

I am working on some  papers and I was wondering if I can publish a draft of them on airxiv in order to receive some feedback and then submit a final version to a journal.

This could be useful also to publish draft of paper that I am not sure to have the time to finish.

I would like to know some advices on how to use or how don't use this site.
I was also wondering how much does a publication on airxiv matter from a career point of view.

Comment: What is your career? That will impact the answers you get fairly substantially.

Comment: It's a duplicate especially because of the question about getting feedback.

Comment: All of the posts in the [arxiv](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arxiv) tag serve as "Tips for publishing draft manuscripts on arxiv." If you have a more specific question that isn't already answered, please edit this post and flag for reopening.